# How to run a for loop (or other approach) on two column range

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a for loop that I'm using for some web scraping. As an example, say it is gathering historic stock data.

```
start <- 1533103200
end <- 1549004400

company <- c("fb","amzn","f")

for (i in company){
    print(paste('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/',i, '/history?period1=',start,'&period2=',maxDate,'&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d',sep=""))
}
```

Start and End are date codes. Now, I have a data.frame of start and end date codes (100 day intervals) that I want to also get into the list of printed links, meaning that instead of three links I want 3 x nrow of the following data.frame. In this example, it would be 6 links...

```
start <- c(1533193200,1541833200)
end <- c(1541746800,1549004400)
dates <- as.data.frame(cbind(start,end))
```

The list is dynamic and long, so I have have to probably embed the for-loop in another for loop, but I don't have much experience using two variables for this purpose. Any help would be great!

Expected results would be....

```
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
```

...instead of the results from just the first loop as...

```
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1533103200&period2=1548918000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1533103200&period2=1548918000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1533103200&period2=1548918000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I streamlined your `data.frame` construction a bit:

```
df <- data.frame(
  start = c(1533193200, 1541833200),
  end = c(1541746800, 1549004400)
)
```

Then I would allocate new columns in that `data.frame` for every company:

```
companies <- c("fb", "amzn", "f")
df[, companies] <- ""
```

Now you can iterate over the new columns and fill them with the links:

```
for (i in companies) {
  df[, i] <- paste0(
    'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/',
    i, '/history?period1=',
    df$start,
    '&period2=',
    df$maxDate,
    '&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
}
```

You get a nice clean `data.frame` with the links for each company in a seperate column:

```
> df
       start        end
1 1533193200 1541746800
2 1541833200 1549004400


fb
1 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
2 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
                                                                                                              amzn
1 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
2 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
                                                                                                              f
1 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
2 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
```

You can "tidy" this up if you prefer a column with the links and the other columns serving as meta information about the links:

```
df_tidy <- tidyr::gather(df, company, url, -start, -end)

> df_tidy$url
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"  
[2] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"  
[3] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[4] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[5] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1533193200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"   
[6] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1541833200&period2=&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
```

Comment: Interesting. I like this approach, as it's a bit more manageable than loops inside loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over company AND dates.

```
start <- c(1533193200,1541833200)
end <- c(1541746800,1549004400)
dates <- as.data.frame(cbind(start,end))

companies <- c("fb","amzn","f")

string <- 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/history?period1=%s&period2=%s&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d'

for (company in companies) {
  for (date in 1:nrow(dates)) {
    date <- dates[date, ]
    print(sprintf(string, company, date["start"], date["end"]))
  }
}

[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/amzn/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1533193200&period2=1541746800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
[1] "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/f/history?period1=1541833200&period2=1549004400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
```